# when a new notification arrives, my AlertDialoge gets closed

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-dialog

I need to show an `AlertDialog` in one of my Activities and when the user presses back button or touches outside the dialog, it doesn't get closed. I can do that by the methods of the class but when a new notification arrives to the status bar of the system, my `Alertdialoge` gets closed and I really don't want that. how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure this is the answer you want but you can do a work around.
Implement a `BroadcastReceiver` that receives notifications and when it does waits a second and launch you alert dialog again.

UPDATE:
Try this: create an activity with the dialog theme declared in the manifest, something like this:

```
<activity android:name="DialogActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
  android:taskAffinity="" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

this way your activityDialog is going to be detached from your main app.

Comment: have you tried to use this `android:taskAffinity=""` in your activity that launches the dialog?

Comment: then what should I write in ""?

Comment: nothing. Just put it like this: `<activity android:name="YourActivity" 
            android:taskAffinity="">
        </activity>`

Comment: I will update my answer with a more complete code. But i still think that the 1 answer is the one you will have to use...